# Handling ZMQ multiple PULL ports

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq, pull

I have project where multiple ZMQ PUSHers (impemented in nodejs) push data to different tcp ports. I need to PULL those data into a single C++ application. My current implementation uses different threads to PULL from each port. Is there any built-in method to connect to multiple ports to a same socket in zeromq?

pull thread (each thread connects to a different pull port)

```
uint16_t port = 4001;
void *context_pull = zmq_ctx_new();
void *requester_pull = zmq_socket(context_pull, ZMQ_PULL);
zmq_setsockopt(requester_pull, ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(int));

int len = sprintf(pub_url, "%s%s%u", (char *) "tcp://", "127.0.0.1:", port);
pub_url[len] = '\0';

int pull = zmq_connect(requester_pull, pub_url);
if (pull < 0) {
    printf("CAN NOT BIND TO PORT %s\n", pub_url);
} else {
    printf("PULL PROCESS CONNECTED TO PORT %s\n", pub_url);
}

char buf[256];

while (1) {
    int rep = zmq_recv(requester_pull, buf, sizeof (buf), 0);
    if (rep > 0) {
        add_log(json::parse(std::string(buf)));  //this method handles the received json data
    } else {
        printf("DATA PULL ERROR!"\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using threads for each socket, you can use `zmq_poll()` to wait on multiple sockets in a single thread. When data is available on a socket, `zmq_poll()` returns and you can process all the sockets that have data available.

`zmq_poll()` can also wait on "normal" file descriptors if that is required.

See [the documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-poll) for more details, including an example.